# Writing model.summary() as a function

Tags: python-2.7, keras

I have a model written as a function that looks like this:

```
def __baseModel(self, nodes=300, lr=0.001):
        _model = Sequential()
        _model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=self.inputDim, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
        _model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
        _optimizer = self.get_optimizer(learn_rate=lr, dcy=float(self.cfg['init_decay']), eps=float(self.cfg['init_epsilon']))
        _model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return _model
```

This function is in a python file called `classifier.py`. I will be calling this function in another python file called `demodel.py` which has the code the train/predict on the model. Finally, in `main.py` I would like to call a function where I can just print the model summary. My question is, in which file should I write a function that prints out the model summary and how would I write such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object-oriented concepts for this, then you do not have to write your own `model.summary` function

Basically you use a *Singleton design pattern / class* for the *keras* model, this Singleton you can then access from any other file / module / class.

You create **only one instance** of this Singleton class in `main.py`, in any other file / module you access only this single instance you created in `main.py`( therefore Singleton ), by this you can access the same *keras model* from the entire program :

**modelsingleton.py**

```
class ModelSingleton():
# Here will be the instance stored.
__instance = None



@staticmethod
def getInstance():
    """ Static access method. """
    if ModelSingleton.__instance == None:
        ModelSingleton()
    return ModelSingleton.__instance 

def __init__(self):

    self.model = self.baseModel()

    """ Virtually private constructor. """
    if ModelSingleton.__instance != None:
        raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
    else:
        ModelSingleton.__instance = self


def baseModel(self):
   nodes=300
   lr=0.001
   model = Sequential() 
   model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=4, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid')) 
   #optimizer = self.get_optimizer(learn_rate=lr, dcy=float(self.cfg['init_decay']), eps=float(self.cfg['init_epsilon']))
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   print('model generated')
   return model
```

**main.py**  ( here you create the single instance of ModelSingleton in that your keras model is defined )

```
import modelsingleton
import demodel

model_instance = modelsingleton.ModelSingleton()

model_instance.model.summary()

demodel.defineModel()
```

**demodel.py** ( in this you **get an instance** of the ModelSingleton create `main.py` )

```
import modelsingleton


def defineModel():
    model_instance = modelsingleton.ModelSingleton.getInstance()

    model_instance.baseModel()

    print('summary demodel')
    model_instance.model.summary()
```

The code above simply prints two model summaries, on from `main.py`, the other from `demodel.py` and calls `baseModel()` from `demodel.py` ( via `defineModel()` in `main.py` )

i adapted the code in https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098129, alternative to write the Singleton

An alternative is in https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html

Comment: Thanks! Your code works! I will now go and understand singleton.